# Adding REST support to application

Tags: rest

I have a requirement to provide REST support to my application. Currently my application is in Linux, it has CLI commands available to configure it. I want to add REST API support to it such that I can configure my application using REST calls too. I want to have a simple HTTP server just for the REST calls and then map those requests to the respective CLI commands for addition, deletion, updation.

Can anyone provide me some info on what I should look at, tools available to perform the same, some good links to look at.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. (copied from flag dialog)

Answer (score 1):

You could try subclassing the `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class in Python3.

It has a simple interface for your needs. Simply add the `do_<Method Name>` functions to your subclass that respectively create the command line arguments and invoke your application.